# SSMS 18.5 installation

Tags: ssms, windows-10-v1909

I'm a bit of a novice and struggling to install [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) on my PC.  I have recently had to reinstall Windows 10 and now cannot get SSMS to install.

I have downloaded the latest version of SSMS from microsoft.com and when I double-click to install (even with 'run as administrator'), nothing happens.  I have a really important personal database in SQL Server which I cannot lose.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check event viewer

Comment: Thanks Dave - hadn't thought of that.  Showing - Application: SSMS-Setup-ENU.18.5.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 63A21152 (63970000) with exit code 80131506. - Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work with a different version of ssms?

Comment: Nope.  Tried version 17.9.

Comment: Interestingly Visual Studio 2019 does the same error - I see the splash screen and then after about 5-6 seconds it has crashed.  The same error is in Event Viewer

Comment: This appears to be a long-standing problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52375069 - but I haven't yet found out what .NET version 18.5 needs. I'll post back if I find out.

Comment: Not resolved by installing .NET 4.7.2 or 4.8.0...

Comment: Cheers Ian - managed to get in touch with Microsoft and it was a fault on the .net 4.8 framework and I was given some tools to rebuild it.  VS 2019 now working but SSMS18.5 now has a side-by-side error.

Comment: All is now sorted - I had to run %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe update /force to regenerate the .NET image.  That made VS2019 work and then I had to uninstall SSMS18.5, remove all directories and a registry key, reboot and reinstall SSMS and that is now working fine too.  Thanks everyone for their help